# adding several json arrays and filtering them according to menu elements clicks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Edit: I've tried to follow the instructions and apparently everytime a query is executed a new array is added, but, when i generate the JSON file, the second array contains the values of the first array and those of the second. What's wrong with this?

Here's my problem: i have to solve two problems:

1) I have to create a JSON file with PHP consisting of a succession of several arrays, like in the following example:

```
{
    "data": {
        "cliente": [
            {
                "id": "Sentra",
                "nome": 4,
                "cognome": "Sentra",
                "indirizzo": 4,
                "email": "Sentra",
                "tipo_contatto": 4,
                "telefono_1": "Sentra",
                "telefono_2": 4,
                "telefono_3": "Sentra"
            }
        ],
        "accettazione": [
            {
                "id": "Sentra",
                "nome": 4,
                "cognome": "Sentra",
                "indirizzo": 4,
                "email": "Sentra",
                "tipo_contatto": 4,
                "telefono_1": "Sentra",
                "telefono_2": 4,
                "telefono_3": "Sentra"
            },                
            {
                "id": "Taurus",
                "data": 4,
                "id_operatore": "Taurus",
                "dispositivo": 4,
                "note": "Taurus",
                "password": 4,
                "tipo_avviso": "Taurus",
                "id_cliente": 4,
                "difetto_dichiarato": "Taurus",
                "codice": 4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here i have two arrays, but i need to have loads of them, anyway, in my PHP page, here's what i have:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('UniversalConnect.php');

class Login
{

    private $hookUp;
    private $sql;
    private $sql2;
    private $sql3;
    private $sql4;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hookUp = UniversalConnect::doConnect();

        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        $this->sql2 = "SELECT * FROM accettazione";
        $this->sql3 = "SELECT * FROM riparazione";
        $this->sql4 = "SELECT * FROM operatore";

        // Tabella cliente

        $response = array();
        $data = array();

        if ($result = $this->hookUp->query($this->sql)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cognome'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['indirizzo'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['tipo_contatto'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['telefono_1'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['telefono_2'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['telefono_3'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                $data[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "nome" => $row['nome'], "cognome" => $row['cognome'], "indirizzo" => $row['indirizzo'], "email" => $row['email'], "tipo_contatto" => $row['tipo_contatto'],
                    "telefono_1" => $row['telefono_1'], "telefono_2" => $row['telefono_2'], "telefono_3" => $row['telefono_3']);

                $response['cliente'] = $data;

                $fp = fopen("cliente.json", "w");
                fwrite($fp,json_encode($response));
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }

        // Tabella accettazione

        if ($rs = $this->hookUp->query($this->sql2)) {
            while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['data'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['id_operatore'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['dispositivo'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['note'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['password'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['tipo_avviso'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['id_cliente'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['difetto_dichiarato'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw['codice'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                $data[] = array("id" => $rw['id'], "data" => $rw['data'], "id_operatore" => $rw['id_operatore'], "dispositivo" => $rw['dispositivo'], "note" => $rw['note'], "password" => $rw['password'],
                    "tipo_avviso" => $rw['tipo_avviso'], "id_cliente" => $rw['id_cliente'], "difetto_dichiarato" => $rw['difetto_dichiarato'], "codice" => $rw['codice']);

                $response['accettazione'] = $data;

                $file = file_get_contents("cliente.json");
                $data = json_decode($file);
                unset($file);
                file_put_contents("cliente.json", json_encode($data));
                unset($data);

                $fp = fopen("cliente.json", "w");
                fwrite($fp,json_encode($response));
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }
}

$worker = new Login();

?>
```

The file executes four queries. In the first i create the json file, and the first query creates the first array, then with the second i create the second, and the second, "accettazione", has to become the second array separated by a comma on the first one, and so on...

Unfortunately, when the second query is executed, the second array becomes the first array, it doesn't become the second after the first one. I know how to push new objects to an existing array, but that's not the situation.

2) The second question is about how this data should be generated in my page:

In the following code, when i click on a "a" tag, the "linked" piece of code (i don't attach it here, but it's an html div), the code is shown (it's an empty table), which has to host the JSON data. As you can see from the example, tmp_div is a sort of array which indicates the content (div 0, div 1, div 2, div3).

The idea is that, when I click on tmp_div 0, json.data.cliente have to be shown, and the same for the others, but i want to do it dinamically, not everytime specifying different cases. How do i have to edit the code to reach the goal?

```
<!--Funzione di selezione della voce del menu e dell'apparizione dei relativi dati-->

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.sidebar-menu a').click(function (e) {
        hideContentDivs();
        var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
        $(".main-sections div").eq(tmp_div).show();

        $.getJSON("lista.json", function(json){

            if (tmp_div == 0) {
                var data = json.data.cliente;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var object = data[i];
                    for (property in object) {
                        var value = object[property];
                        console.log(property + "=" + value);
                    }
                }
            } else if (tmp_div == 1) {

                var data = json.data.accettazione;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var object = data[i];
                    for (property in object) {
                        var value = object[property];
                        console.log(property + "=" + value);
                    }
                }
            } else if (tmp_div == 2) {
                var data = json.data.riparazione;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var object = data[i];
                    for (property in object) {
                        var value = object[property];
                        console.log(property + "=" + value);
                    }
                }
            } else if (tmp_div == 3) {
                var data = json.data.operatore;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var object = data[i];
                    for (property in object) {
                        var value = object[property];
                        console.log(property + "=" + value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    });

    function hideContentDivs() {
        $(".main-sections div").each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }

    hideContentDivs();

</script>
```

Comment: why would the order of each array matter? they're keyed by name, not index?

Comment: what's the difference if i give them a name instead of an index? The name of my divs are not numbers, but they're indexed as if they were

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your first question:**

> Unfortunately, when the second query is executed, the second array
>   becomes the first array, it doesn't become the second after the first
>   one. I know how to push new objects to an existing array, but that's
>   not the situation.

Right now you're calling `$data = array()` in your loop. You're overwriting the existing array each iteration of the loop. Because of that, `$data[] = ...` will always push to element 0, since it's pushing onto an empty array.

Furthermore, you're doing this: `$response['cliente'] = $data;` which means you will always rewrite `$response` with whatever `$data` is. This is not pushing new objects onto an existing array; you are always overwriting your arrays.

**To answer your second question:**

This is more of a design question in the end. You have a lot of possible answers. A very quick thing you can do for now would probably be make a function, but that's just a small step forward. You may have better advice in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: So what should i do in the first question? What value $data should have? I've found that, if i remove that, the second array includes the array values of the first query and of the second one. I don't want to achieve this... For the second question, thanks, i'll write here.

Comment: Made a brief edit to my post. You need to not declare arrays and files inside loops. They will get overwritten and you will not get values as desired.

Comment: Ok, and i'm ok with you, but how could i obtain the rows data outside of the loops and put the results all together on the json file?

Comment: Push each result set onto the array. After the loop is done, encode the single array as JSON and save it to a file.

Comment: Great! understood. you've 1/2 saved my day :)

Comment: Sorry, but in the for cicle, why if i use " document.getElementById("tab-3").innerHTML = value; " the result is the last voice of the array and if i use ".append" all the array data is put there? i would use innerHTML because .append appends me the data every time i click on the link and i want it to appear at the first click

Comment: @dabadee You're setting the value each time you go in the loop. It will always end with the last item of the loop since you overwrite the previous values. Same idea as earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83522/discussion-between-dabadee-and-mari-m).

Comment: I think i didn't catch at all what you've said with "Push each result set onto the array. After the loop is done, encode the single array as JSON and save it to a file.".